# SQL Server CREATE tables with types

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a table that has a choice of 2 types. The main table is product with:

- ProductCode
- ProductName
- ProductPrice
- ProductStockLevel
- ProductType

It then splits into 2 choices, food and non-food. Under food, it will have expiry date and under non-food, it will ask for classifications such as bedding, clothes, cosmetics etc. It will then have the offer id, offer period and offer price as the last 3 columns for both.

Example:

[image: Table with each type]

What is the query needed to create the 2 types or how do I go about doing something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the Query needed to create the 2 different Types

Comment: How will you get offerID, startOffer, endOffer, offerPrice if it is not in the main table since your main table has only 5 columns.

Comment: That’s the part I’m not sure how to do. Basically, I’m trying to create a table where depending on the Type, it would then require different specifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 :  Using CHECK constraint**

Your query should be like below :

```
CREATE TABLE Product (ProductCode int, ProductName varchar(255),
                      ProductPrice float,ProductStockLevel int, 
                      ProductType varchar(255) NOT NULL CHECK (ProductType IN('Food', 'Non-Food')))
```

And keep the two columns `Class` and `ExprDate`.

- If the Type is Food set Class to `Undefined`.
- If the Type is Non-Food set ExprDate to `9999-12-31`.

**Solution 2 : Implementing Table Inheritance in SQL Server**

Start by creating a Base Table - Deriving Sub-Tables from the Base Table
 :

```
create table Product(ProductCode int primary key, ProductName varchar,ProductPrice float,ProductStockLevel int )

create table FoodProduct(ProductCode int primary key references Product(ProductCode ), ExprDate date)
create table NonFoodProduct(ProductCode int primary key references Product(ProductCode ), [Calss] varchar(255))
```